# Excel Date to java.Uitl.Date using jXLS Reader

Tags: jxls

I am trying to read excel files using jXLS library with Spring 3.x.
The problem is I have a couple of date columns in excel file with mm/dd/yyyy format but when I am reading them back into java bean, they are turning up as NULL.

I tried the conversion mechanism mentioned in [jXLS Reader](http://jxls.sourceforge.net/reference/reader.html#Conversion_Mechanism)

Am I missing any configuration or implementing jXLS configuration wrongly? TIA.

Answer (score 1):

You can check [XLSReader](https://bitbucket.org/leonate/jxls-demo/src/48c446aa5851da94075db73f29cf8137438f00c3/src/main/java/org/jxls/demo/reader/XlsReaderDemo.java?at=master) example in https://bitbucket.org/leonate/jxls-demo project. 
It reads `Employee` birth dates into `java.util.Date birthDate` property and prints them.
The [XML configuration](https://bitbucket.org/leonate/jxls-demo/src/48c446aa5851da94075db73f29cf8137438f00c3/src/main/resources/org/jxls/demo/reader/departments.xml?at=master) for this part looks like this

```
        <section startRow="7" endRow="7">
            <mapping row="7" col="0">employee.name</mapping>
            <mapping row="7" col="1">employee.age</mapping>
            <mapping row="7" col="2">employee.birthDate</mapping>
            <mapping row="7" col="3">employee.payment</mapping>
            <mapping row="7" col="4">employee.bonus</mapping>
        </section>
```

In the [input Excel file](https://bitbucket.org/leonate/jxls-demo/src/48c446aa5851da94075db73f29cf8137438f00c3/src/main/resources/org/jxls/demo/reader/department_data.xls?at=master) you should have properly formatted Date cells like `8/18/1978`.

Comment: I tried this approach but it was not working since the default [DateConverter](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/net.sf.jxls/jxls-reader/0.9.9/net/sf/jxls/reader/DateConverter.java) class of jxls reader can only parse a Double, Number & a String representation of Double but not a "mm/dd/yyyy" formatted date. Are you using any parsing /formatting settings in between?

Comment: POI reads the Date value in Excel as Double so in DateConverter it is first converted to double and then if the target data type is java.util.Date the method "DateUtil.getJavaDate( date )" is invoked which returns the correct date (in the old Jxls-reader version the method used was HSSFDateUtil.getJavaDate( date ) which is specific to .xls). You can check the example link - there are no other additional code. The only thing you need is to have proper Date cell formatting in Excel and the target bean data type should be java.util.Date

Comment: I tried exactly the steps mentioned by you but not able to get it converted. I debugged the code in jxls DateConverter.java and it is getting date as "mm/dd/yyyy" and throwing exception.
I made it worked by registering apache beanutils DateConverter and its working like charm. thanks for your help though.. :)

Comment: Glad you have resolved it. It may happen that you have the excel date formatted as a String in the input Excel file. If it is not the case then to track down the issue a code and Excel example would be required so that it is possible to reproduce.